# MySQL INSERT Fatal -> 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]:

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a function that does an INSERT:

```
function insertData($data){
    global $dbh;
    $sql = sprintf(
        "INSERT INTO location " .
            "(" .
                "data1, " .
                "data2, " .
                "data3" .
            ") " .
        "VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s')",
            $data['data1'],
            $data['data2'],
            $data['data3']
        );

        echo "$sql \n";
        $adjusted = $dbh->quote($sql);
        $stmt   = $dbh->prepare($adjusted);
        $stmt->execute();
        $lastId = $dbh->lastInsertId();

        return $lastId;
}
```

When the function is called, I get this error:

```
INSERT INTO location (data1, data2, data3) VALUES ('Blah1', 'Blah2', 'Blah3')
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''INSERT INTO location (data1, data2, data3) VALUES (\'Bl' at line 1' in /var/www/test/lib/saveData.php:59
>       Stack trace:
>       #0 /var/www/test/lib/saveData.php(59): PDO->prepare(''INSERT INTO lo...')
>       #1 /var/www/test/lib/saveData.php(10): insertData(Array)

If I run the insert directly it works fine.
I can't figure out what PDO does not like about my syntax.

UPDATE:

Is there a significant difference between using the paramaterization

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO location (data1, data2, data3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
```

or

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO location (data1, data2, data3) VALUES (:data1, :data2, :data3)";
```

*UPDATE 2*

```
function insertData($data){
    global $dbh;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO location " .
            "(" .
                "data1, " .
                "data2, " .
                "data3, " .
                "data4" .
            ") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";

        $stmt   = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($data);

        $lastId = $dbh->lastInsertId();

        return $lastId;
}
```

*UPDATE 3 - A debrief For the sake of other readers*

I was being clever with `sprintf()` based on an example I picked up somewhere.
Using `sprintf()` to build the sql statement is not the same as using named or anonymous bind parameters, so I used the '?' bind parameter and everything worked fine.

Also, I am stuck building on an old system for now, so the shorthand `[]` array notation was also interfering with successful completion of the task.

Thanks for the input to those who responded.

Comment: Why are you using quote on the entire SQL string O_o

Comment: Please read about [using prepared statements in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).  There are many undesirable things about your current PHP script.

Comment: Remove `$adjusted = $dbh->quote($sql);` thats adding BackSlashe(Escapes) around your quotes. Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: There is little point preparing a query that you have already concatenated the data directly into. It protects you from NOTHING

Comment: `"INSERT INTO location "."("."data1, "."data2, "."data3".") "."VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s')"` see you query error is in this

Comment: Ok. Thanks folks. I see that there are a number of problems I have invoked.

Comment: There is no difference between the named and unnamed parameters as such. When passing the data to execute you need to use associative array with named parameters and their order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not preparing your statement correctly. `sprtinf` and `quote` are breaking your query. Get rid of them and pass the values to `execute`

```
function insertData($data) {
    global $dbh;
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO location 
        (
            data1, 
            data2, 
            data3
        ) VALUES (:data1, :data2, :data3)';

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array(
        'data1' => $data['data1'],
        'data2' => $data['data2'],
        'data3' => $data['data3']
    ));
    $lastId = $dbh->lastInsertId();

    return $lastId;
}
```

**Update:**
I have added named placeholders, but I am still building the array manually. If you are sure that `$data` contains exactly the number of items matching your placeholders you can pass it in directly to `execute`.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. That makes sense. I thought I was being clever with sprintf and it devolved into concatenating in pieces because some of the data has double quotes.

Comment: I tried this but the data is not inserting. No errors, but no data either.

Comment: I used this $stmt->execute($data);

Comment: $insert = mapPostData($_POST);
  $id = insertData($insert);

Comment: I concatenated because the actual data is 17 columns. It's difficult to check the consistency otherwise.

Comment: I saw an example where the whole array was passed to execute.

Comment: I updated the answer, and I used named placeholders. Pay attention to the number of items in your array and their keys. The placeholders and keys have to match 1 to 1.

Comment: I just noticed that the machine I'm working on is using PHP 5.3. Is there a chance that is a problem point?

Comment: I had to explicitly list the 17 columns. The functionality I was trying to use is not available in the PHP version I am stuck using. Thanks for the assistance. The data insert is working fine now.

Comment: The only thing I see which is not available in your version is the short array syntax. Use `array()` instead of `[]`

Comment: Yep. That was it.